# When will the safe string functions of C11 be part of glibc?

Tags: c, glibc, c11, tr24731

The C11 standard Annex K defines a bunch of new safer string functions, all suffixed by *_s* (e.g. *strcpy_s*).

Do you know when these new functions will become available in the GNU C library glibc?

So far you have to fall back to a third party library like [safec](https://sourceforge.net/projects/safeclib/).

Comment: The annex is optional. And why don't you ask this at the GCC's project site?

Comment: A document of interest → http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based because only the glibc developers and maintainers can answer this question.

Comment: @olaf because GCC has nothing to do with glibc?

Comment: @rubenvb: Please read the homepage of the GNU Compiler Collection **project**! You are wrong! GCC != gcc!

Comment: These functions aren't all that great as they're made out to be. See for example, [thi write-up](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).

Comment: @olaf: The GCC project page, http://gcc.gnu.org, contains exactly zero references to glibc. What are you on about? Glibc is not part of the GCC project.

Comment: @rubenvb: The page is not well sorted, I agree. However, according to the intro text: "The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for **C**, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go, **as well as libraries for these languages** (libstdc++, libgcj,...). ". And I have in mind that they also maintain glibc. However, I could not find a direct link quickly. Anyway, then ask GNU, resp. the glibc maintainers directly. Whoever the maintainer is, stack overflow is definitively not, nor the support forum.

Comment: There is *nothing* opinion-based in this question, and the answer I gave is precise and correct. I don't understand all the down-votes. Source: I *am* a GLIBC developer.

Comment: Note that safec is now here: https://github.com/rurban/safeclib
with all C11 Annex K functions.
Can be used together with glibc or any other libc to get the secure Annex K functions

Comment: This is the GNU and Standards and coding world just shooting itself in the foot.  If you have the online docs (ie what folks use when they look up C strcpy_s for example, declare it is part of C11 ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy ) then it is right that a user expects compilers claiming to implement C11 to have that as part of the implementation.  When G++ for example claimns to cover C11, such as as of GCC 4.7, then I think its right for the programmer to expect GCC 4.7 will compile code with strcpy_s in it.  And not complain about "undefined".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you know when these new functions will become available in the GNU C library glibc?

When someone contributes an implementation and convinces GLIBC maintainers that these functions are good to have.

Relevant [thread](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2007-05/msg00028.html) from 2007.