# strerror_s,strcpy_s,localtime_s,sprintf_s not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, gnu

I have written a cross-platform code gives a current date(mm/dd/yy) and time(hh/mm/ss) and complete date(yyyymmdd), This code works in windows(MSVS2015) but not working in Linux(GCC 4.8.5).

My code is

```
#include <iostream> 
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <cerrno>
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#include <direct.h>
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <ctime>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdlib>  /*atol*/
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <size_t size>
void GetNowDateTime(char(&c_date)[size], char(&c_time)[size])
{
   time_t t;
   struct tm now;
   strcpy_s(c_date, "00/00/00");
   strcpy_s(c_time, "00:00:00");
   time(&t);
  if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return;
 char temp[3];
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_mon + 1);
 memcpy(c_date, temp, 2);
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_mday);
 memcpy(c_date + 3, temp, 2);
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_year - 100);
 memcpy(c_date + 6, temp, 2);
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_hour);
 memcpy(c_time, temp, 2);
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_min);
 memcpy(c_time + 3, temp, 2);
 sprintf_s(temp, "%.2d", now.tm_sec);
 memcpy(c_time + 6, temp, 2);
 }

  int GetToday(void)
  {
    time_t t;
    struct tm now;
    time(&t);
    if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return 0;
    return (now.tm_year + 1900) * 10000 + (now.tm_mon + 1) * 100 + now.tm_mday;
  }

 bool OpenOuputFile(ofstream& outputFile)
 {

  char buf[1024];

 #ifdef WIN32
   strcpy_s(buf, "C:\\Myfolder\\output.txt");
  #else
    strcpy_s(buf, "/home/myfolder/output.txt");
    #endif
    outputFile.open(buf, ios::out);

    if (!outputFile)
    {
    char szErrorMsg[1024];
    strerror_s(szErrorMsg, errno);
    cout << "Unable to open input file. " << buf << " Error:" << szErrorMsg << endl;
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

//Here is my main function

```
int main()
{
char today[9];
char time[9];
ofstream outputFile;
GetNowDateTime(today, time);
int yyyymmdd = GetToday();
if (OpenOuputFile(outputFile))
{
    outputFile << "GetNowDateTime functions given is:-\t" << today << "\t" << time << endl;
    outputFile << "GetToday Function given is:-\t" << yyyymmdd << endl;
   }
   else
    cout << "No output file written" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Errors in Linux is

```
TimeDate.cpp: In function ‘void GetNowDateTime(char (&)[size], char (&)[size])’:

TimeDate.cpp:34:26: error: there are no arguments to ‘localtime_s’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘localtime_s’ must be available [-fpermissive]
  if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return;
TimeDate.cpp:36:40: error: there are no arguments to ‘sprintf_s’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘sprintf_s’ must be available [-fpermissive]
imeDate.cpp: In function ‘int GetToday()’:
TimeDate.cpp:55:26: error: ‘localtime_s’ was not declared in this scope
if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return 0;
TimeDate.cpp:74:31: error: ‘strerror_s’ was not declared in this scope
strerror_s(szErrorMsg, errno);
TimeDate.cpp:31:29: error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
strcpy_s(c_date, "00/00/00");
```

This program runs on (windows )visual studio 2015 and(Linux) GCC 4.8.5.

I included all required headers but It showing errors when compiling in Linux.

why above errors showing in Linux, Please tell me.

Comment: Why are you using C string functions in a C++ program? Use `std::string`.

Comment: I was compilng other people's C++ code that used a lots of strcpy_s, strcat_s, ... Tried a few trick with gnu compiler could not get rid of the error message.  Anyone has a way of making this function legal?  Other choice is to convert old C (disguised as C++) into real C++ string operations.

Answer (score 5):

`strcpy_s` and friends were Microsoft extensions to c, they were standardised in C11. GCC 4.8.5 doesn't support them and newer versions probably don't either  [When will the safe string functions of C11 be part of glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322363/when-will-the-safe-string-functions-of-c11-be-part-of-glibc)

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf_s` and the other `_s` functions are not part of Standard C++.  Your program will be restricted to compilers which have those functions as a non-standard extension.

Comment: ,I removed _s most of the errors rid but some errors are still remains They are:- **TimeDate.cpp: In function ‘void 
TimeDate.cpp:42:26: error: cannot convert ‘tm*’ to ‘const time_t* {aka const long int*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘tm* localtime(const time_t*)’
  if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return;
                          ^
TimeDate.cpp: In function ‘int GetToday()’:
TimeDate.cpp:63:26: error: cannot convert ‘tm*’ to ‘const time_t* {aka const long int*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘tm* localtime(const time_t*)’
  if (localtime_s(&now, &t) != 0) return 0;**

Comment: @kusalava - If you have a new question, please ask a new question.